# How to disable mobile data, in a way that's hard to re-activate, while still allowing mobile calls, for a child's phone?

Tags: settings, mobile-data

I want to disable mobile data in the phone settings for my child in a way that makes it hard to re-activate it. Just turning off the "mobile data" setting is far too tempting for them to undo.

What I've tried:

1. Under Settings > Connections > Mobile Networks > Network Mode, I updated the setting to "2G only", which disabled mobile data but also disabled mobile calling. So that doesn't work.
2. Under Settings > Connections > Mobile Networks > Access Point Names > Data, I tried changing the "APN" value and also (separately) tried changing the "Mobile virtual network operator value", but mobile data still worked with either of those options changed.

Is there a different setting that will disable mobile data while still allowing mobile calls?

Am using Android 10 on a Samsung phone in New Zealand.

Comment: Hello. Is using a firewall app (and therefore denying internet access to all apps) not an option on the table?

Comment: Changing the APN as also my first idea. Unfortunately some MNO don't use them any more and just accept any APN value.

Comment: @Firelord Yes, that could be an option I think, though I do want to allow Wifi access. Are you aware of any firewall apps that can do that?

Comment: Search for any "no root firewall" type firewall in Play store. Firewall apps usually allow internet access per network configuration -- an app can be blocked on mobile data but allowed on wifi, ethernet, etc. An opensource alternative is called NetGuard.